# Split and replace special characters from column names in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which has column names like this:

```
id, xxx>xxx>x, yy>y, zzzz>zzz>zz>z, ...
```

I need to split by the second `>` from the right side, replace `>` with `-`, and then take the last element as new column names, `id, xxx-x, yy-y, zz-z, ....`

I have used: `"-".join('zzzz>zzz>zz>z'.rsplit(">", 2)[-2:])` and it gives: `zz-z`, but when I apply this to all column names with: `"-".join(df.columns.str.rsplit(">")[-2:])`

Out:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Comment: so you are just trying to rename the columns right ? the number of columns in the end will be the same

Comment: Looking at the error, are you sure all elements in your column are strings?

Comment: Yes, i think they all are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
col_names = ["id", "xxx>xxx>x", "yy>y", "zzzz>zzz>zz>z"]

new_names = [col_names[0]] + [
    col_name.split('>')[-2] + '-' + col_name.split('>')[-1]
    for col_name in col_names[1:]
]

print(new_names)
```

Returning:

```
['id', 'xxx-x', 'yy-y', 'zz-z']
```

Comment: I have a more concise answer to this issue: `df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('>', 2).str[-2:].str.join('-')` :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

c = ['id', 'xxx>xxx>x', 'yy>y', 'zzzz>zzz>zz>z']
print([re.sub(r"(.*?)([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)$", r"\2-\3", i) for i in c])
```

**Output:**

```
['id', 'xxx-x', 'yy-y', 'zz-z']
```